# Still can't access Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from boot after installing twice in two different ways

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have been trying to figure out on how to solve my problem for nearly 20+ hours, and I still can not seem to figure out the solution.  If anyone has suggestions please do tell me!  Also as a side not, after switching from OS to OS quite a few times, I am not going back to the linux environment to fix the problem until I have a better understanding of what I am dealing with.  Thank you guys in advance for helping me out come up with a solution!

After trying out Ubuntu 12.04 LTS where it is installed as a program under windows 7, I decided to allocate some driver space for the OS to actually install it on my computer so that it can run on its own rather than under windows 7.

Before I installed Ubuntu, I allocated space for the OS by shrinking the C: drive by 100 gb, which is where I am going to install Ubuntu.

I installed Ubuntu with the "Install along side windows 7 option" selected with no problems.  But when I restarted my computer, it loaded windows 7 immediately with no boot menu displaying.  I restarted again and once more the menu did not show up.  So I figured that maybe I installed it incorrectly so I installed it again.

When I installed Ubuntu, this time I selected the last option in the install options.  This led me to a window that shows all the /dev/sda options on where I am going to install Ubuntu.  Now the thing that confuses me is that the 100 gb space I allocated is called dev/sda5 ext 4.  There was a free space option but that was only 20 gb in size.  Since the 100gb /dev/sda5 ext 4 option seems the proper place to put Ubuntu, this is where I selected to install.

After installation, I restart the computer and once again it boots up windows 7 immediately with no boot menu specifying which OS I can select.

I checked under disk management in windows and the space that I allocated for Ubuntu under windows stills says that 100 gb unallocated.  Shouldn't it say something else?  Or is that normal or did I do something wrong?

Any advice would be much appreciated on how I can fix this problem!

Below I will post the results of running boot info script:

```
     Boot Info Script 0.61      July 19 2013


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos4)/boot/grub on this drive.
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of 
    /dev/mapper/isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE29743 and looks at sector 1 of the same 
    hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks for 
    (,msdos4)/boot/grub on this drive.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Dell Utility: FAT16
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sda1 already mounted or sda1 busy

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sda1 already mounted or sda1 busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sda1 already mounted or sda1 busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sda1 already mounted or sda1 busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
mount: /dev/sda4 already mounted or sda4 busy

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sda1 already mounted or sda1 busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
mount: /dev/sda4 already mounted or sda4 busy
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297431: __________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sda1 already mounted or sda1 busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
mount: /dev/sda4 already mounted or sda4 busy
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297432: __________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sda1 already mounted or sda1 busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
mount: /dev/sda4 already mounted or sda4 busy
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297433: __________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sda1 already mounted or sda1 busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
mount: /dev/sda4 already mounted or sda4 busy
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297434: __________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sda1 already mounted or sda1 busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
mount: /dev/sda4 already mounted or sda4 busy
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                  63        80,324        80,262  de Dell Utility
/dev/sda2    *         81,920    41,627,647    41,545,728   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3          41,627,648 1,748,717,567 1,707,089,920   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda4       1,748,717,568 1,953,523,711   204,806,144  83 Linux


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0 GB, 32017047552 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3892 cylinders, total 62533296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1               2,048    16,775,167    16,773,120  84 OS/2 hidden C: drive


Drive: isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE29743 _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE29743: 1000.2 GB, 1000202698752 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953520896 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/mapper/isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297431                 63        80,324        80,262  de Dell Utility
/dev/mapper/isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297432   *         81,920    41,627,647    41,545,728   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/mapper/isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297433         41,627,648 1,748,717,567 1,707,089,920   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/mapper/isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297434      1,748,717,568 1,953,523,711   204,806,144  83 Linux

/dev/mapper/isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297434 ends after the last sector of /dev/mapper/isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE29743

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        5450-4444                              vfat       DellUtility
/dev/sda2        60F237A5F2377DFA                       ntfs       RECOVERY
/dev/sda3        D2043A90043A7795                       ntfs       OS
/dev/sda4        1d8c79d0-2d5c-4313-bc82-d42171717622   ext4       
/dev/sr0                                                iso9660    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS amd64

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sr0         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297431


Unknown BootLoader on isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297432


Unknown BootLoader on isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297433


Unknown BootLoader on isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297434



========= Devices which don't seem to have a corresponding hard drive: =========

sdc 

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

ERROR: dos: partition address past end of RAID device
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
hexdump: /dev/mapper/isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297431: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297431: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297432: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297432: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297433: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297433: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297434: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/isw_cgcfhffaff_XW133CE297434: No such file or directory
ERROR: dos: partition address past end of RAID device
```

Comment: Do you have EFI in your BIOS system?

Comment: Yes I have EFI in my BIOS system...does this affect how Ubuntu is installed?!

Comment: Also I have tried boot repair and still nothing, and I also tried EasyBCD but there is no option to add Linux Ubuntu as part of the menu....which confuses me even more since I just installed Ubuntu twice....any ideas?

Comment: Also I just want to point out that does anyone know why there are multiple lines in the boot script stating "fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy"?

Answer (score 1):

This might help. You need to hold down the SHIFT key on your keyboard the entire time your computer boots up. This will go straight to your GRUB screen if grub is installed correctly.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, nothing appeared.